# put the hand in onclick Event

Tags: html

I have this code in a HTMl table

```
<tr id="${item.deviceId}" class="odd" onclick="window.location.href='<c:url value='/devices/app-${item.applicationId}' />'">
```

But I don't see the cursor when I put the mouse over the table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try style="cursor:pointer";

```
<tr id="${item.deviceId}" style="cursor:pointer" class="odd" onclick="window.location.href='<c:url value='/devices/app-${item.applicationId}' />'">
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you, in CSS you can add this to an element to force the hand pointer icon:

```
cursor: pointer;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `cursor: pointer` property for `odd` class

example:

```
.add{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add "cursor: pointer" in line style or you can mention it in css and use it.